# Android leanback tv is crashing on launch

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

Hi when I open the android tv app , the app is crashing by showing this which is internal to android . Can anyone tell why its crashing.

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);getMainFragmentRegistry().registerFragment(PageRow.class,
                    new PageRowFragmentFactory(mBackgroundManager));
            }
```

**Error Logs**

```
 Process: com.firestick.shemaroome, PID: 11453
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseSupportFragment$FragmentFactory.createFragment(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseSupportFragment$MainFragmentAdapterRegistry.createFragment(BrowseSupportFragment.java:671)
    at android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseSupportFragment.createMainFragment(BrowseSupportFragment.java:597)
    at android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseSupportFragment.replaceMainFragment(BrowseSupportFragment.java:1532)
    at android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseSupportFragment.setSelection(BrowseSupportFragment.java:1522)
    at android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseSupportFragment$SetSelectionRunnable.run(BrowseSupportFragment.java:253)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

Comment: Show some code. Where are you calling `createFragment()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @ManoharReddy this is different and one i have posted the question is different .